# Accessing a generic process inbox using EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use EWS to access a process mailbox.  For some automated queries we created a genric process mailbox. I want to parse emails by watching the Process inbox.

My code was working earlier with the old exchange server. But after migration to office 365 it fails.

I am able to access my mailbox and parse on the office 365 using my credentials.

How do I access this process mailbox? Earlier I create an ExchangeService and connect to the process email address with UseDefaultCredentials = true.

I set the AutoDiscoverURl and used DefaultCredentials. But When I tried to read emails I get "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."

EDIT:
I tried to use my own credentials instead of the Default Credentials.

```
string smtpaddress = "somesharedsmtp@domain.com";
es.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
es.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myemail", "mypassword");
es.AutodiscoverUrl(smtpaddress, RedirectionCallback);
FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "somesharedsmtp@domain.com");
Folder sharedInbox = Folder.Bind(es, SharedMailbox);
```

At this point I can check sharedInbox containing the details of the Inbox. I can see the unread email count and others.

But when I access

```
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(100);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults1 = es.FindItems(pqInbox.Id, itemView);
```

I get exception "SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disclaimer: I haven't worked with EWS in a while.

You can't use the default credentials for Office 365. You'll need to provide either the basic credential or use an OAuth token.

You should confirm that the account was migrated to Office 365. Login to OWA and look at the URL to make sure you are using Office 365 and not an on-premise server.

This was already answered by [Exchange Web Services: UseDefaultCredentials property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481717/exchange-web-services-usedefaultcredentials-property?rq=1)

Comment: This solved the first part of accessing the mailbox. I am able to access but not able to enumerate the mail items.

Comment: Can you login in to OWA with somesharedsmtp@domain.com? Can you turn on the trace and show the results of the ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl call? You don't have to use Autodiscover with Office 365, but it may provide some insights into what is going on here.

Comment: If I use my credentials I am able to see the Process Inbox along with my own on the browser. Why the FIndItems failing is something I cannot understand..

Comment: Can you turn on tracing and get the output for the find item call and paste it here? Post both the request and response. Sanitize before posting.

Comment: One thing I observed is the email address on the response is not my generic inbox instead my email address is coming.. I removed the xml headers as it is too long to post..

Comment: I am able to access thru OWA using the following https://xchangeserver/owa/sharedemail@domain.com then I need to give my credentials.. But not thru EWS.. If that server is not Office 365 any other ways?